# Access Denied to Putty Login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, putty

I just installed Debian therefore have no password or username.  I cant login with putty because I get Access Denied.  I can not try anything as I can not connect to the computer (beaglebone-black).

Answer (score 0):

Default user:password for a beaglebone-black is root:toor